# How to handle with warning in C++ inline + template context?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, inline, afx

I'm facing an interesting problem: I had an MFC application project in Visual C++ 6.0. Since there are many changes either in MFC or in C++ standard, I wanted to port my application to Visual Studio 2010. It was fine, but I am facing a warning now, which I can't handle.

The header file has the following class definition:

```
template <class T>
class foo : public CObject
{
// ...
// other stuff
// ...
private:
    CTypedPtrMap<CMapWordToPtr, const long, T*> oElementMap;
    void some_stuff();
}
```

In the source file there is:

```
template <class T>
void foo::some_stuff()
{
// ...
// other stuff
// ...
    int nIndex = 0;
// ...
// other stuff
// ...
    oElementMap.RemoveKey(nIndex);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following warnings:

> Warning   1   warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const long' to
>   'WORD', possible loss of data c:\programme\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h 2066

It comes definetly from the above mentioned "RemoveKey" line: if I just simply comment out that line, I won't get this warning.

I know, the main problem is, that `CTypedPtrMap` object uses `const long` as key type, but `CMapWordToPtr` would have `WORD` (unsigned short) instead of it. But the fact is: I need const long as key type, since I am processing regulary about 1 million data entries in this map, so with `unsigned short` the class would not be capable to do it's job furthermore.

I tried to nest either the "RemoveKey" line or the include of `stdafx.h` into the following expressions, but neither worked:

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4244)
// expression
#pragma warning (default: 4244)
```

Please share me any ideas about this issue, how could I resolve this warning WITHOUT changing the container's `oElementMap` definition and behaviour, and WITHOUT supress/disable this warning globally in the project settings as well as WITHOUT changing the `afxtempl.h` file supplied by VS2010.

Thanks for help:

Andrew

Comment: Do you still get the warning if you write `oElementMap.RemoveKey(static_cast<DWORD>(nIndex));`?

Comment: If you have too many keys for `WORD` and must use `long` instead, then using `CMapWordToPtr` as the base class is going to fail at some point anyway right?

Comment: BoBTFish: Yes, you're right. The problem is, that there doesn't exist a `CMapDwordToPtr` or something like that, it would be useful...

Comment: So you shouldn't be trying to get rid of the warning without changing `oElementMap`s definition. There is a real problem, and you *should* be changing the definition. But agreed, it isn't immediately obvious to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced it's definition to: `CMap<long, long&, T*, T*&> oElementMap;`. I was not sure it is the "long-counterpart" of the old map definition, therefore I did several test to compare them.

The solution was finally this.